# create array in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got buttons with a common class (`buttons`). How can I add their `ID`s in to an array in a reverse order?

```
var yourArray = [];
$('.buttons').each(function() {
     yourArray.push( $(this).prop('id') );
});
```

Comment: `array.unshift()`?

Comment: Add `yourArray.reverse();` outside the loop

Comment: @Mihai - doesn't that just reverse an already created array? `unshift` at least allows one to create an array from back to front ("in reverse order")

Comment: Yes but why does it matter @evolutionxbox

Comment: Flexibility. OP might have more code which prevents a reverse...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create the array by adding each element to the beginning of the array using `unshift()`:

```
var yourArray = [];
$('.buttons').each(function() {
     yourArray.unshift(this.id);
});
```

Alternatively you can create it in the current order and then `reverse()` it. Also note that you can use `map()` to create the array initially:

```
var yourArray = $('.buttons').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().reverse();
```

Finally you can use `this.id` instead of creating a jQuery object just to access a property already accessible without the need of object creation.

Comment: @Becky A POJS array doesn't have an `each()` method. You should use a normal `for` loop or `$.each(yourArray, function() { ... });`

Comment: Is it possible to reverse the order within the existing `each()` function?  `$('.buttons').each(function(){`

Comment: I'm bit lost. Can you please help? `$('.buttons).each(function(){ yourArray.unshift(this.id); var data = $(this).text().replace(/\s*$/g, ''); });` How do I reverse the order for `$(this).text().` ?

Comment: Could you setup a new fiddle for this as I can't quite get what you're trying to do with the `text()`. It may be worth starting a new question if it's a different issue to the above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something simple with **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** and **[`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)**

```js
var yourArray =  $('.buttons').map(function() {
  return this.id; //  get the id
})
.get() // get the array
.reverse(); // reverse the array

console.log(yourArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a" class="buttons"></button>
<button id="b" class="buttons"></button>
```

Comment: How should I use the newly create array if I need to use it in another `each(function(){' ?

Comment: `yourArray.forEach(function(v){........................................});` , use `forEach` or `$.each()`

Comment: Thanks. I want to use it in an existing `each()` function. I tried `yourArray.each(function(){...});` doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @Becky : it's only work with jquery object, not with array